# static member of dynamic library can not be initialized on Linux(GNU GCC) but can initialized on macOS (Clang)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, g++

It seems that the linker of gnu drop `test.cpp` since that there is no reference in main.cpp.
But I really need to initialize some static variable like this in my project.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "test.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
// test.h
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

```
// test.cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
auto print = []()
{
    std::cout << "print" << std::endl;
    return 1;
};
static int x = print();
void A::foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}
```

Linux input:

```
g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.cpp -fPIC -std=c++11
g++ main.cpp -L./ -ltest -o main -std=c++11
```

Linux output:
(nothing)

macOS input:

```
g++ -shared -o libtest.dylib test.cpp -fPIC -std=c++11
g++ main.cpp -L./ -ltest -o main -std=c++11
```

macOS output:

```
print
```

Comment: I suspect [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)

Comment: But it runs well on macOS

Comment: You don't use `x` with the static linkage, the linker doesn't have to include it in the shared library.

Comment: Prints on my Linux machine. What does `ldd ./main` say on your Linux? Is there a mention of libtest.so?

Comment: I didn't find anything about ``libtest.so``. But why?

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp -L./ -Wl,-no-as-needed -ltest -o main -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Fedora 37, the output is:

```
$ ./a.out
print
```

I can reproduce the behavior you observed by linking with:

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -Wl,--as-needed -ltest -Wl,-rpath=. -Wl,--no-as-needed
```

You are *probably* testing on Ubuntu or Debian, where `g++` is configured to use `--as-needed` by default.